# Is $\langle X,Y\rangle =X^*MY $ for $M$ pos. definite and hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra

In paper it says that the inner product of two $n$-dimensional vectors is equal to:

$$\langle X,Y\rangle =X^*MY  $$

where $M$ is Hermitian and positive definite.

I think that it is not true, may be I am wrong. Any idea please!

Comment: I did not read the paper, but why do you think it is not true? You definitely can define inner product in this way - it is easy to prove that it has all needed properties.

Comment: let vectors be real x=[1;1],y=[3,2], M=[2 1; 1 2]. Then above doesn't hold.

Comment: The sesquilinear form defined in the question satisfies the axioms for inner products, but of course if $M\ne I$, then this inner product is not equal to the standard inner product.

Comment: TeX tip: Do not use `<,>` for inner products. Instead use `\langle,\rangle`. Compare: $<u,v>$ to $\langle u,v\rangle$.

Comment: The paper doesn't say that it's *the* inner product, but it's *an* inner product, which is certainly true.

Comment: @Christoph now I understood what is the difference between $\textit{a}$ and $\textit{the}$, after Svinepels response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, if $M$ is positive definite and Hermitian, then
$$ \langle x, y \rangle_M = x^*My $$
defines an inner product on the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$.

However, this is only half of the story. The second half is perhaps more interesting: If $\langle -,- \rangle$ is any inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$, then there *exists* a positive definite Hermitian matrix $M$ such that
$$ \langle x, y \rangle = x^*My $$

In other words, this is a classification of all inner products on $\mathbb{C}^n$: There is a bijective correspondence between inner products on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and positive definite Hermitian $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: Let me understand one by one :Is complex inner-product not a dot product of complex numbers?

Comment: The dot product is only on of many inner products. In general an inner product is defined axiomatically. See the wikipedia page for more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Comment: I think, I am confusing with the notations, is this mean $\langle X,Y\rangle :=X^*MY  $?

Comment: $\langle x, y \rangle$ can refer to any inner product. If you want to talk about a specific inner product you could for instance say: Let $\langle -, - \rangle$ denote the standard Euclidean inner product (dot product). This is also denoted by $x \cdot y$.

Comment: I had a (wrong) thinking before that inner product is just another name of dot product. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is positive defined and hermitian it defines an inner product, it is sufficient to check the [axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) (really easy). If you prefer you can call it a "weighted" inner product.

It's a really useful object with the induced norm. It is often denoted by $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\small M}$.

For example the [CG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) method in numerical analysis is based on a inner product of this type.